# Access Properties of Derived Classes from an Interface in Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created an Interface which is having two derived classes as shown in below code snippets, I want to access members of those derived classes in an `Linq` query but I am unable to do that.

Model Class Structure:

```
public interface IDirDetails
{   
}
public class DirectoryDetails: IDirDetails
{
    public string[] PathElements { get; set; }
    public string[] ApplicationList { get; set; }

    public List<DirectoryItemInfo> Items { get; set; }
}
public class DirectoryItemInfo: IDirDetails
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileIcon { get; set; }
    public DateTime FileModified { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Code form where I am trying to access those members:

```
List<IDirDetails> data = LoadData();                   
int totalRecords = data.Count;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
{
    // Apply search
    data = data.Where(p => p.FileName.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||  //not allowing to access FileName
                           p.FileSize.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||               //not allowing to access FileSize
                           p.FileModified.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList(); //not allowing to accessFileModified
}
```

below is how I'm setting values for those classes in `LoadData()`

```
public List<IDirDetails> LoadData()
{
    string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserName == userName);           
    string[] appList = null;
    var allDirDetails = new List<IDirDetails>(); //obj of an Interface
    var allAppExist = _context.UserApplications.Any(ua => ua.AppId == 17 && ua.UserId == user.Id);

    appList = (from a in _context.Applications
               join ua in _context.UserApplications on a.Id equals ua.AppId
               where ua.UserId == user.Id
               select a.AppName).ToArray();

    DirectoryDetails dirDetails = new DirectoryDetails();
    dirDetails.ApplicationList = appList;

    List<DirectoryItemInfo> dirItems = new List<DirectoryItemInfo>();
    dirDetails.Items = dirItems;

    allDirDetails.Add(dirDetails);  // adding values into DirectoryDetails

    string requestPath = Request.Path.Value;

    string[] requestPathParts = requestPath.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    dirDetails.PathElements = requestPathParts;

    var aapId = _context.Applications.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AppName == requestPathParts[0].ToString());

    string[] physicalPaths = (from ap in _context.ApplicationPathElements
                              join a in _context.Applications on ap.AppId equals a.Id
                              where a.Id == aapId.Id
                              select ap.AppPathElement).ToArray();
    if (physicalPaths != null && physicalPaths.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string indexPath in physicalPaths)
        {
            DirectoryItemInfo details = GetDirectoryInfo(indexPath, indexPath + "/", DateTime.MinValue);        
            allDirDetails.Add(details); // adding values into DirectoryItemInfo
        }
    }            
    return allDirDetails;
}
```

Can someone please suggest about how should I access required members of a derived classes from an Interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer on your question is: just cast it

```
data = data.Cast<DirectoryItemInfo>().Where(p => p.FileName.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||  
                       p.FileSize.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||             
                       p.FileModified.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
```

or use `OfType`

```
data = data.OfType<DirectoryItemInfo>().Where(p => p.FileName.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||  
                       p.FileSize.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||             
                       p.FileModified.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
```

**Right answer is**:  Something is wrong with your model. Either your don't need a List of interface, but the list of specific type, or you should move these properties to interface.

For example your `LoadData` method returns a list of interface, but in your example you use it as list of specific class. You could  change it as :

```
public List<T> LoadData<T>()  where T:IDirDetails
{   
    // return specific List
}
```

After that you could call it as:

```
List<DirectoryItemInfo> data = LoadData<DirectoryItemInfo>();
```

and you don't need cast. Somewhere in the `LoadData` you should decide which elements you will return.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, can you please suggest the correct way to achieve these?

Comment: @RahulNagrale  I don't  see your whole code, i made one suggestion in the answer, but it really depends on what are you doing exactly.

Comment: it is showing an error when I'm returning `List<IDirDetails>` from `LoadData()`, Error: `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IL_LogViewer.Models.IDirDetails>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'`

Comment: @RahulNagrale sure it does. Either you returns List of DirectoryItemInfo and use it as DirectoryItemInfo. Or you return list of interface and you use it as an interface.

Comment: sir, I followed the updated code which you have provided in an answer, i.e. modified `LoadData()` to `public List<T> LoadData<T>()  where T:IDirDetails` and now also returning `List<DirectoryItemInfo>` but still showing an error. Please see the Error: `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IL_LogViewer.Models.DirectoryItemInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'`

Comment: @RahulNagrale you should cast your List to List<T>, somehting like: return new List<DirectoryItemInfo> {new DirectoryItemInfo()} as List<T>;

Comment: that seems to be work, but as I'm returning an instance of List<DirectoryItemInfo> `objDirDetails` how should i write this in a above return statement?

Comment: The same: return objDirDetails as List<T>;

Answer (score 0):

You can take all items from 'data' list with 'DirectoryItemInfo' type using 'OfType' method, and cast result of 'Where' to 'IDirDetails' list back.

```
data = data.OfType<DirectoryItemInfo>()
           .Where(p => 
                  p.FileName.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                  p.FileSize.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||  
                  p.FileModified.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
           .ToList<IDirDetails>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only access those members that are defined by your interface. If you need to access the members of a concrete implementation of that interface, you'll need an instance of the concrete implementation (in your case, an instance of `DirectoryDetail` or `DirectoryItemInfo`.

You can do some things with casting as other members have said, but you're still accessing an instance of a concrete implementation in some way or another.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OfType` to filter the type

```
List<IDirDetails> data = LoadData();                   
int totalRecords = data.Count;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
{
    // Apply search
    data = data.OfType<DirectoryItemInfo>().Where(p => p.FileName.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||  
                           p.FileSize.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||               
                           p.FileModified.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).Cast<IDirDetails>().ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: `Cast` won't work if there are `DirectoryDetails` in the list.